# If we have a graph with 2 nodes, the flow added to one edge will be added as extra capacity to be second edge

Tags: graphs

If we have the following subgraph of a graph where I will just show 2 nodes please, where the capacity is 7 and 2 respectively:

[image]

Now, if we have received flow at node 1 of value 5, then we will have:

[image]

**Problem**: could you please explain why this will cause the capacity to be added to edge 2 and thus edge 2 will have now a capacity of $2+5 = 7$ given that we know a capacity of edge is supposed to be fixed if I understand it right and flow across edge should be less than the capacity of an edge please?

[image]

Comment: All the explanation is given in CLRS. Could you please specify what you did not understand from the text?